# Does Inheritance Broken Event Fire with Remote Event Receiver?

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

Does Inheritance Broken Event Fire with Remote Event Receiver?

I have tried since Past couple of weeks, with Same logic, Item Added event work with Remote Event Receiver but Inheritance Broken Event not working.

Inheritance Broken Event work with SPSecurityEventReceiver (SharePoint On premise) but not with SharePoint online.

I have configure Azure, SharePoint apps , Service Bus SAS with Azure Powershell ( Iteam Added events works as expected in Remote Event Receiver but face the issue while working with Inheritance Broken Events)

Please suggest your views on this.

you can find project from here.

[Inheritance Broken Remote Event Receiver](https://gujaratgas-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/himanshu_gujaratgas_onmicrosoft_com/EbpZx5WQ4OdEogKqOHKZV7sBkNObq3uVwOuow_xkKc9q5A?e=uzcRV1)